# Sauerkraut with trace amount of detergent

Tags: fermentation

I'm new to fermentation and I'm making my first sauerkraut. I have followed the basic instructions correctly but when I crushed the cabbage in order to get the water out, my hand had a little bit of detergent on it, very small amount. I don't know if it rubbed off and stayed on the cabbage but at the end, the water on top of the jarred cabbage was a foamy, more so than the pictures I saw on the internet. So my question is: Will that trace amount of detergent prevent fermentation? I cannot wash it with water and re-add the salt now because I only got chlorinated water available so it's either bite the bullet, throw it all out or eat 2 pounds of cabbage before it goes bad.

Any inputs or references will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This describes the effect of detergent when fermenting cassava:

> #### Abstract
>
> The effects of detergent on the microbiological changes of cassava for fufu production were investigated for a period of 72hr.
> Microbiological analyses of the fermenting cassava samples using standard methods were carried out.
> Six microbial species: Lactobacillus plantarum, Citrobacter freundii, Corynebacterium manihot, Lactobacillus cellobioscus, Pseudomonas alcaligens, and Leuconostoc mesenteriods were identified for the control.
> The same organisms were identified for the low detergent concentrations (1g/L, 2g/L) except Corynebacterium manihot, Leuconostoc mesenteriods, which were completely destroyed.
> High detergent concentrations (4g/L, 8g/L) inhibited the growth and subsequently killed all the organisms living[sic] very few Citrobacter freundii behind.
> At low detergent concentrations the cassava ferment within 48hr without objectionable odour.
> However, at high detergent concentrations there was no fermentation even after 72hr.
> The control samples fermented after 72hr with undesirable odour.
>
> — [*The Effects of Detergent on the Microbiological Changes of Fermenting Cassava for Fufu Production*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/250355728_The_Effects_of_Detergent_on_the_Microbiological_Changes_of_Fermenting_Cassava_for_Fufu_Production),
> Eki T. Aisien and Felix Aisien, 2007

Lactobacillus is the primary agent when fermenting sauerkraut, so one might presume that the effects will be similar.

While high levels of detergent kill the bacteria (no fermentation), low levels have no noticeable effect.

Your "little bit of detergent" could be low level (less than 1g/L), in which case you should see signs of fermentation, and the taste of samples of the cabbage should improve over time.

Comment: I'm glad to inform you that my sauerkraut is bubbling like crazy! thanks!